# Integer partitions in all orderings

Tags: partitions

I want to partition an integer into $k$ integers all possible orderings. This can be done in the following way

```
integerPartitions[n_, {k_}] := Select[FrobeniusSolve[Table[1, {k}], n], FreeQ[#, 0] &]
```

For example,

```
integerPartitions[4, {2}]
```

gives

```
{{1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}}
```

But this is very slow if the partition number is large as compared to `IntegerPartitions`, which gives partitions in reverse lexicographic order. For instance, `integerPartitions[60, {5}]` will take more than 4 seconds in my laptop in contrast to 0 seconds of `IntegerPartitions[60, {5}]`.

So my question is: what would be the most efficient Mathematica code for this problem?

Comment: Can't you apply permutations to the results of `IntegerPartitions` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems to be quite quick :

```
output = Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[60, {5}], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.245025, Null} *)

output // Dimensions
(* {455126, 5} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If order does matter, you are generating integer compositions. Integer compositions are related to the operation multichoose. You can use the Resource Functions [IntegerCompositions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/IntegerCompositions/), where 0 s are allowed like {0,0,5} for 5 into 3 parts, and [StrictIntegerCompositions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StrictIntegerCompositions/) for this, where 0 s are not allowed like {2,1,2} for 5 into 3 parts.

Comment: Please add the specific code to be used to obtain the desired results