# Find all permutations with a condition

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

How can I find all the permutations of `{a, b, c}` where `a + b + c = n`?

For instance: if `n = 3` the permutations I seel are:

- `Permutations[{3, 0, 0}]`
- `Permutations[{2, 1, 0}]`
- `{1, 1, 1}`

Comment: Related: [(19486)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19486/121)

Comment: good find @Mr.Wizard ! I searched for ages permutations-related questions but not IntegerPartitions...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
f[sum_, quant_] :=
  Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[sum, {quant}, Range[0, sum]], 1]

f[3, 3] // Column
(*
{3,0,0}
{0,3,0}
{0,0,3}
{2,1,0}
{2,0,1}
{1,2,0}
{1,0,2}
{0,2,1}
{0,1,2}
{1,1,1}
*)

f[4, 2] // Column
(*
{4,0}
{0,4}
{3,1}
{1,3}
{2,2}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
f[sum_, quant_] := FrobeniusSolve[Array[1 &, quant], sum]

f[3, 3]

(*
    {{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 2}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}
*)

f[4, 2]

(* {{0, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}} *)
```

Comment: For readibility purpose, may I suggest: `ConstantArray[1, quant]` instead of `Array[1 &, quant]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
(* a crude way: lets assume we wish to find all the permutations of a list of three integers that add up to 4 *)

Select[Permutations[Flatten@ConstantArray[Range[0, 4], 3], {3}], 
Plus @@ # == 4 &]
```