# Find all permutations with a condition (part 2)

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

[This question (21008)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21008/find-all-permutations-with-a-condition) asks to find all permutations of `{a, b, c}` subject to `a + b + c = n`.  The answer was provided by Dr. belisarius using `IntegerPartitions`.

How can we generalize that answer to find all permutations of
`{a, b, c}` subject to `2 a + b + c = const`, or more generally find all partitions subject to `{a, b, c, d, e, ...}` subject to `2 a + b + c + d + e + ... = n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html)?  e.g. for $2 a + b + c = 5$

```
FrobeniusSolve[{2, 1, 1}, 5]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 5}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 2, 3}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 4, 1}, {0, 5, 0},
>  {1, 0, 3},  {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 0}}
> ```

Comment: * facepalm! *  If the answer is that simple, then the best thing to do is to accept this answer, and close this question because "it can easily be found in the documentation".

Comment: @QuantumDot It happens to all of us. :^)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
g[sz_, n_] := Partition[Flatten[Map[Thread[{
    #/2, f[n - #, sz - 1]}] &, Range[0, n, 2]]], sz]
g[3, 5]
```

> {{0, 5, 0}, {0, 0, 5}, {0, 4, 1}, {0, 1, 4}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 2, 3}, {1,
>      3, 0}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}}

where `f` is defined in the question you mentioned:

```
f[sum_, quant_] := Flatten[Permutations /@
                    IntegerPartitions[sum, {quant}, Range[0, sum]], 1]
```